# Php code to include header.php not working correctly

Tags: php, templates

I am using these codes so that I can pass the file needed or other attribute through variables but it is not working properly. I don't know what the problem is because the code looks pretty fine to me. Index page does not show any content from header's page.

**`helper.php`**

```
<?php
function render($template, $data = array())
{
    $path = $template . ' .$php ';
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        extract($data);
        require($path);
    }
}
```

**`header.php`**

```
<?php require_once('helper.php') ?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($title); ?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

**`Index.php`**

```
<?php
    require_once('helper.php');
    render('header', array('title' => 'Index'));
?>
```

Comment: Well, at least one issue will be `' .$php '`. Unless you really have a space before the extension `.` and a `$` before `php`, but that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you must want this line

```
$path = $template . ' .$php ';
```

to actually be this:

```
$path = $template . '.php';
```

Comment: yeah..didnt saw it through, stupid mistake. It is working now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
$path = $template . ' .$php ';
```

You are adding spaces and a `$` sign to your path:

```
$path = $template . '.php';
```